# Dimmable LEDs flicker in non-dimmer circuits

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, led

I recently installed new LED bulbs in two identical fixtures (hanging fixtures on opposite sides of a room). One fixture already had LED bulbs (non-dimmable), and the other had CFLs. I got tired of two different bulb types, color temperatures, and warm-up time on one end of the room but not the other. Plus I wanted to increase the overall light level in the room. The new bulbs are dimmable LED bulbs, but there is no dimmer switch on either fixture.

One fixture (the one that already had non-dimmable LED bulbs, with no issues whatsoever) now has an intermittent flicker, while the other (the one that had CFLs) gives solid, steady lighting. I've tried swapping bulbs around, within and between fixtures, to no avail. I've tried to determine which bulb(s) is flickering, or if it's one specific socket, but can't seem to nail anything down. If I leave one socket (doesn't seem to matter which) of the offending fixture empty, the flickering stops.

Neither fixture has a dimmer switch, both are on (separate) 4-way switches. Both fixtures are older (probably mid-90s), meant for four 100W incandescent bulbs each, so I'm pretty sure wattage is not the issue. While I increased (by about 10W) the total wattage on the offending fixture, that's still about 20W less than the other fixture had with CFLs.

Any ideas about what I can do, short of installing new fixtures?

Comment: Are any fans involved?

Comment: Nope, no fans. Each fixture has its own set of switches that control that fixture and nothing else.